# What's the best way to classify a high dimensional int-vector with the weka API?

Tags: java, classification, weka, bayesian, decision-tree

I have some high dimensional (30000 dimensions) vectors of integer numbers. I have 2 classes: [YES, NO]. I have 6000 samples of the YES-class and 50000 samples of the NO-class. I would like to train a classifier, to classify new samples in future automatically to one of these classes.

I know how to use the Weka Java API, but I am not sure which algorithms in which order to use. Can anyone give me advice on the following questions:

1. Are the vectors too high dimensional or do I have too many samples to do this efficiently in Weka?
2. Should I reduce the dimensionality before I start? What algorithm can I use to identify significant elements of my feature vector?
3. What classifier would be best to classify this kind of data? I think a decision tree should work fine, but maybe a naive bayes is faster to train, is it?
4. Since every element must have a name in weka, how can I assign a name to each of my 30000 features?

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. The number of dimensions to this problem most certainly are quite large, but I believe that Weka should be able to handle a large number of dimensions.  The number of samples should not be a problem, but there are a lot more NO class samples than there are YES Class, so balancing the two might assist in classifying the NO Class cases better.
2. If you believe that there are redundant dimensions or some of the dimensions may contain noise, then it would certainly help.
3. A decision tree shouldn't be too much of a problem.  There are a number of algorithms available in Weka, but I wouldn't recommend Neural Networks given the dimensionality of the problem.
4. If you have saved the data in a CSV File, you could assign attribute names in the first row of the data.  This way, you can assign attribute names.  Given the number of dimensions, you would likely call these a1 to a30000 and output for the output class.

Hope this Helps!